Using Matplotlib's AuxTransformBox to Rotate Artists Leading to Unexpected Behavior
Up front: totally open to other methods that might accomplish the same thing - I thought this would be the most straightforward way to accomplish this.
Start by importing the following modules:
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.artist
import matplotlib.lines
import matplotlib.pyplot
import matplotlib.patches
import matplotlib.patheffects
import matplotlib.offsetbox
import matplotlib.transforms

Problem 1: Nested AuxTransformBoxes
Let's say I want to create a line that is 2 inches long and rotated 45 degrees:
# Creating a 5x5 plot
fig, ax = matplotlib.pyplot.subplots(1,1, figsize=(5,5), dpi=150)
# Creating a line
line = matplotlib.lines.Line2D([0,2],[2,2])
# This box will scale and rotate
atb = matplotlib.offsetbox.AuxTransformBox(fig.dpi_scale_trans + matplotlib.transforms.Affine2D().rotate_deg(45))
# Adding the line to the box
atb.add_artist(line)
# AOB will contain the final artist, and is used for centering
aob = matplotlib.offsetbox.AnchoredOffsetbox(loc="center", child=atb, frameon=False, pad=0, borderpad=0)
# Adding the AOB to the plot
ax.add_artist(aob)

This "works", although the line has been shifted considerably:

However, this method that uses two AuxTransformBoxes nested together does not work - you can see the line hiding at the very bottom edge of the figure, not rotated:
# Creating a 5x5 plot
fig, ax = matplotlib.pyplot.subplots(1,1, figsize=(5,5), dpi=150)
# Creating a line
line = matplotlib.lines.Line2D([0,2],[2,2])
# This box will ONLY scale
atb_scale = matplotlib.offsetbox.AuxTransformBox(fig.dpi_scale_trans)
# Adding the line to the box
atb_scale.add_artist(line)
# This box will ONLY rotate
atb_rotate = matplotlib.offsetbox.AuxTransformBox(matplotlib.transforms.Affine2D().rotate_deg(45))
# Adding the previous atb to this one
atb_rotate.add_artist(atb_scale)
# AOB will contain the final artist, and is used for centering
aob = matplotlib.offsetbox.AnchoredOffsetbox(loc="center", child=atb_rotate, frameon=False, pad=0, borderpad=0)
# Adding the AOB to the plot
ax.add_artist(aob)


Repeating this process, but turning the frame of the final AOB on, reveals that the AOB is where it should be - but the line contained within isn't being drawn correctly inside of it.
# Creating a 5x5 plot
fig, ax = matplotlib.pyplot.subplots(1,1, figsize=(5,5), dpi=150)
# Creating a line
line = matplotlib.lines.Line2D([0,2],[2,2])
# This box will ONLY scale
atb_scale = matplotlib.offsetbox.AuxTransformBox(fig.dpi_scale_trans)
# Adding the line to the box
atb_scale.add_artist(line)
# This box will ONLY rotate
atb_rotate = matplotlib.offsetbox.AuxTransformBox(matplotlib.transforms.Affine2D().rotate_deg(45))
# Adding the previous atb to this one
atb_rotate.add_artist(atb_scale)
# AOB will contain the final artist, and is used for centering
aob = matplotlib.offsetbox.AnchoredOffsetbox(loc="center", child=atb_rotate, frameon=True, pad=0, borderpad=0)
# Adding the AOB to the plot
ax.add_artist(aob)


Why would this be the case? Nested OffsetBoxes clearly work sometimes, but can you not nest AuxTransforBoxes together to interatively apply transformations?
Problem 2: Rotating Other OffsetBoxes
I was hoping to apply these AuxTransformBoxes to other types of OffsetBoxes, such as HPackers and VPackers that mix text and artists, but that doesn't seem to work either.
This is a code snippet that stacks a text area and a line artist vertically:
# Creating a 5x5 plot
fig, ax = matplotlib.pyplot.subplots(1,1, figsize=(5,5), dpi=150)
# Creating a line
line = matplotlib.lines.Line2D([0,2],[2,2])
# This box will ONLY scale
atb = matplotlib.offsetbox.AuxTransformBox(fig.dpi_scale_trans)
# Adding the line to the box
atb.add_artist(line)
# Creating a TextArea
txt = matplotlib.offsetbox.TextArea("Example")
# This will pack the atb and txt artists together vertically
vpack = matplotlib.offsetbox.VPacker(children=[txt,atb], align="center")
# AOB will contain the final artist, and is used for centering
aob = matplotlib.offsetbox.AnchoredOffsetbox(loc="center", child=vpack, frameon=False, pad=0, borderpad=0)
# Adding the AOB to the plot
ax.add_artist(aob)


However, the same code does not work when everything is placed inside of an AuxTransformBox that is rotated (the frame of the AnchoredOffsetbix is kept on here):
# Creating a 5x5 plot
fig, ax = matplotlib.pyplot.subplots(1,1, figsize=(5,5), dpi=150)
# Creating a line
line = matplotlib.lines.Line2D([0,2],[2,2])
# This box will ONLY scale
atb_scale = matplotlib.offsetbox.AuxTransformBox(fig.dpi_scale_trans)
# Adding the line to the box
atb_scale.add_artist(line)
# Creating a TextArea
txt = matplotlib.offsetbox.TextArea("Example")
# This will pack the atb and txt artists together vertically
vpack = matplotlib.offsetbox.VPacker(children=[txt,atb_scale], align="center")
# This box will ONLY rotate
atb_rotate = matplotlib.offsetbox.AuxTransformBox(matplotlib.transforms.Affine2D().rotate_deg(45))
# Adding the vpacker
atb_rotate.add_artist(vpack)
# AOB will contain the final artist, and is used for centering
aob = matplotlib.offsetbox.AnchoredOffsetbox(loc="center", child=atb_rotate, frameon=True, pad=0, borderpad=0)
# Adding the AOB to the plot
ax.add_artist(aob)


Again, the composite artist is found at the bottom of the screen, not respecting where the AnchoredOffsetBox tries to place it. Why would this be the case?

It’s hard to parse all these questions, or understand what you are trying to do and why.  Please limit to one well defined question at a time.

@JodyKlymak fair critique, here's a more direct version.
